# Table View Cell Lags when scrolling with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The UIImage is loaded and after scrolling passed 1 cell, it lags and continues the same for others.

Is it because of the cell reusable ?
[image]

```
extension TableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return post.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                //MARK:- UIImage as URL
                let postImage = self.post[indexPath.row]
                if let photoUrl = URL(string: postImage.photoUrl!)
                {
                    do {
                        let data = try Data(contentsOf: photoUrl)
                        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (data: data)
                        cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 450, height: 450)

                    } catch {
                        print("")
                    }
                }// postImage
            }
            return cell
        }

    } //MARK:- Extension into Table View Controller
```

Comment: NEVER access remote data on the main queue.

Comment: NEVER load many, large-size pictures with the collection cell or the table cell.

Comment: I required to load the feeds with 1:1 picture on my table view cell. Are there any alternative solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It lags because you are doing "heavy" operation on main thread. DispatchQueue.main.async doesn't help here because it still performs the code in main thread. You really have to do on main thread just these two lines of code:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (data: data)
cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 450, height: 450)
```

Actually you don't even need second one because layout should be done by the cell itself (you can set it via constraints or autoresizing mask for example)

The heaviest operation in your code is `let data = try Data(contentsOf: photoUrl)` because it performs data loading from network. So your main goal is to perform this operation out of main thread. For example you can do it like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: photoUrl)
        let image = UIImage(data: data) // this also could be pretty much heavy if the image is big so since we're already in background let's do it here
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            imageView.image = UIImage (data: data)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("")
    }
}
```

This example is pretty much basic and still has unsolved problems. For example, if image is very large than scaling it when it's set to imageView also could be expensive, so you'd better also scale image to imageView size in background thread. Also cells are reusable so when one image is loaded the cell could already be used for displaying another image so you also need a way to handle it. Also you'll probably want to cache loaded images to avoid reloading them from network every time on scroll.

So there's a lot of work to do here and to make it easier I'd recommend using some library like [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) (not advertisement just as an example)

Comment: i have inserted that sample code, but having "invalid conversion..."

Comment: Anyway thanks @anton ! I should resize my images before posting to my table view cells ! <3

Comment: @WengieLoh yeah forgot to wrap it all in do-catch. Fixed it, thank you